# Sorting a list based on calculated values

Tags: c#, linq

I'm struggling trying to sort a list based on values that need to be calculated.

In a university I have different departments. Every department has a number of studyareas that in their turn have a number of students.

Currently all of those studyareas are in one big list, but I would like to sort the list based on the total number of students in every department.

```
public class StudyAreasClass()
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public string Students {get; set;}
   public string Department {get; set;}
}
```

In the list there might be four StudyAreaClass-items where the Department is the same. So I would need to calculate the total amount of students where the Department is the same.

Then I would need to sort that comparing the value of this department with the other departments in the university.

The tricky part is that I don't have a fixed value to compare with. So I won't know which departments are in my list. So I can't just say:

```
University
.OrderBy(s => s.Students)
.Where(c => c.Name == "NameOfADepartment")
.ToList();
```

I'm thinking that there should be a somewhat easier way to sort this class using Linq, but I have no idea how to do it.

Can anybody point me out in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: I don't still fully understand the question, but in the `OrderBy` method you can put any kind of expression, and the objects will be sorted according the result of that calculation.

Comment: Look into `GroupBy`; you can Group By départment and u will get a key value pair wherein the key is the department and the value will be records for that department

Comment: You object has students as a string.  Is that really the type or should it be a collection of students?

Comment: @CodingYoshi: thank you for the tip. I'll look into it.

Comment: @bhmahler: No the Students is an integer. But for clarity purposes I stripped a lot out of the class and copy/pasted a few delarations. So it was just to give the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use linq query to do this

```
    static void Main()
    {
        List<StudyAreasClass> areas = new List<StudyAreasClass>();
        areas.Add(new StudyAreasClass() { Name = "A", Students = 5, Department = "D1" });
        areas.Add(new StudyAreasClass() { Name = "B", Students = 1, Department = "D1" });
        areas.Add(new StudyAreasClass() { Name = "C", Students = 2, Department = "D2" });
        areas.Add(new StudyAreasClass() { Name = "D", Students = 10, Department = "D3" });

        var sortedList =
            from area in areas
            join sub in (from a in areas
                         group a by a.Department into g
                         select new
                         {
                             Department = g.Key,
                             StudentCount = g.Sum(x => x.Students)
                         }) on area.Department equals sub.Department
            orderby sub.StudentCount, area.Students
            group area by area.Department into g2
            select g2;



        foreach (var departmentList in sortedList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(departmentList.Key);
            foreach (var area in departmentList)
                Console.WriteLine(area.Name);
        }

        //D2
        //C
        //D1
        //B
        //A
        //D3
        //D
    }
```

basically you use a sub query to compute the sum of total students group by department and join the original list. Then you can sort based on the total count and get the result after.

Comment: Thanks Steve, this is almost exactly what I need. However would there be a way to put this in a sort of sublist? So I would get a list of 4 Departments with in each department a list of StudyAreasClass that is part of this department?

Comment: @Cainnech you can add another group by statement. Answer updated

Comment: Thank you Steve, but this way I can't access the sortedList directly can I? If I would want to see the sortedList[0].Department[0].Area[1].Name for example?

Comment: sorted list is an IGrouping<string, StudyAreasClass> object, where the key is the department name. If you want to do something complex instead of just printing the sorted result then you should make another class and populate it using the sorted list.  Something like a sorted dictionary